# Objects in section can't be resized to fit to section size CSS/HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a landing page and have some troubles making it responsive.

I am using scrollify jQuery library so user on click or scroll, skips between sections of my landing page.

When using the mobile version and changing the orientation so it's landscape the objects in my section go over the sections.

Here is one of my sections

```css
.inner2 {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.centerwraper {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.centerdiv {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.coltitle {
  width: 50%;
}

.colimage {
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<section class="panel OriginalCollection" data-section-name="OriginalCollection">
    <div class="inner2">
        <div class="stripe">
            <br>
        </div>
        <div class="centerwraper">
            <div class="centerdiv">
                <img class="coltitle" src="img/original_header.png" />
            </div>
            <div style="width: auto">
                <div class="centerdiv">
                    <img class="colimage" src="img/original_bottles.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="centerdiv">
                    <div style="padding-left: 30px" class="descriptions">
                        <p2>
                            The real MVP of the fruity
                            <br> flavours. Perfect for those
                            <br> looking for a one of a kind taste
                            <br> sensation. A true
                            <br> mouth-watering fruit explosion
                            <br> that your taste buds have
                            <br> been waiting for.
                        </p2>
                    </div>
                    <div style="padding-left: 60px" class="descriptions">
                        <p2>
                            A top secret recipe that can
                            <br> only be described as the daddy
                            <br> of all day vapes. A fruity
                            <br> undertone and a cool crystal
                            <br> after sensation that will leave
                            <br> you wondering what it is...
                            <br> and wanting more.
                        </p2>
                    </div>
                    <div style="padding-left: 80px" class="descriptions">
                        <p2>
                            Packed with one hell of a bite.
                            <br> This flavour is crammed with
                            <br> sweet red cherries blended
                            <br> perfectly with fresh picked
                            <br> forest fruits. The fruity taste is
                            <br> then entangled beautifully with
                            <br> sweet eucalyptus and aniseed.
                        </p2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Also, to get the sections to be the right size, user have to refresh the website is the size changes. E.g. if you have the orientation you have to refresh the page to get the right size of the sections.

Comment: Hi, you can use GitHub pages option to host your site for free.  If you can, please host there and share the link. thanks

Comment: Hi there, I have just unlocked the website it's www.konceptxix.co.uk

Comment: Worth a read: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428). In general site links are not good to post, since when the question is resolved and the site is fixed, the link will no longer demonstrate the problem, and future readers of the question will be searching the link in vain for the issue. Put it in the question instead if you can.

Comment: Hi there. You are right, it's worth a read and I do understand now that it's not a good practise. Will keep this in mind next time :) Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for responsive please include the **viewport** meta tag in the header.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

The link which you provide is missing with this tag. This may help you.

Comment: I thought that might help but if I add this, this messes the whole thing completely.

Comment: Yep, you need to add above line completely, for documentation please visit the link which I have given below. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Comment: That completely broke the design of the site, does that mean I have to do it from scratch when it comes to mobile version?

Comment: I have gone through your code, there have some minor things to improve in CSS. If you need more assistance to fix that page, feel free to ping me @ ssksatheesh.s11@gmail.com